# Make a server on call on every first of the month

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-alarms

I am building a game and now I have to *send user scores on every first of the month to the server* .

I have multiple options like

- Timer
- ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
- Service
- BroadcastReciever with AlarmManager.

but not sure which one to use.
for the following reasons:

I don't think *Alarm* or *Timer* will be the best as *it doesn't make sense to have an alarm after every month as user may can install the app at any date*.

besides that I can't even check the date from user device as *what if the user has wrong time set on device*?

And what if the *user doesn't have the internet connection available at first of the month or what if he didn't launch the app on the first*.

I know we can use service for this problem but again *is it feasible to always run the service in background which only requires once a month*?

I checked other SO post too like this [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

but its not same as my case as I only have to make the calls once in a month.
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your downvote I know I am not best here but only a downvote won't improved me but a comment about downvote will.Thanks

Comment: Okay for the one who vote it as close please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android this should also be off topic then but its not. Don't know why.

Comment: How about u simply check current date and if its first then simply send score to server?

Comment: @kevz what if he didn't launch the app on the first

Comment: Simply create a service which will run once in a day and will check the date.If the date is 1st of a month then it will send the score to the server

Comment: @SyedaZunairah: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25784137/1878151

Comment: Thanks this seems to solve my problem thanks alot

Comment: @SyedaZunairah: glad that answer helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
AlarmManager is your best bet.
```

Your Issue:-

while scheduling an alarm check the current date and schedule the alarm accodingly EX:- if today is 17th schedule alarm after 14 day.

Regarding getting the current date put the current date on server and get it from there

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will check that. +1

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should write a service and execute timer in your service which will be executed after every 24 hours and than if you don't want to get date and time from user device you can use google API or any other API for getting time and than decide if app needs to update score or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. will try this one too and than get back to you :)